# bytestring-lexing-0.4.3.2 failed during the configure step

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
cabal install hedis
```

This failed due to its dependency - `bytestring-lexing` not getting installed. The error message is,

```
bytestring-lexing-0.4.3.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
hedis-0.6.5 depends on bytestring-lexing-0.4.3.2 which failed to install.
```

To reason why this package failed, I grep-ed for local installations of `bytestring-lexing` using this command,

```
 ghc-pkg field bytestring-lexing depends
```

But there are no local packages,

```
ghc-pkg: cannot find package bytestring-lexing
```

Now it is not the version conflict, what else could cause this error?

Comment: Maybe try installing `cabal install bytestring-lexing` and then try again with `hedis` installation ?

Comment: Sibi, that solved it da.... please make this as answer. in btw, `bytestring-lexing` needed `alex` which i solved by the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is simply indicating that it's not able to find the package `bytestring-lexing`. So try installing that package first:

```
cabal install bytestring-lexing
```

And then try again the installation of `hedis`.